# html5 regexp in php

Tags: php, regex, html

For only alpha numeric characters I use something like this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" />
```

When the data reaches the server I need to validate again. So I did

```
preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9]+", $value);
```

But PHP says Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '+'

Can't you use the same expressions in html5 and PHP?

Edit:
I have a JSfiddle showing the suggestions below don't work:
http://jsfiddle.net/EY3hc/

What I want to achieve is 1 regex I can use as pattern in html and in preg_match. The html is generated by PHP so I'd like to have one place to maintain code for validation.

Comment: I just had a hearty LOL at 5 identical answers within 20 seconds of each other.

Comment: @JanDvorak, it wouldn't matter anyway. I answered first and still got 0 votes :P

Comment: @maček turns out the only one to notice the missing delimiter won the price by quality :-)

Comment: @maček Yeah I noticed, you deserve an upvote :P

Comment: @MathieuImbert but so does the rest, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @maček you were only first by four seconds. :(

Comment: Sorry guys but the answers is only half helpful. I'll ad some to the start post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add delimiters in your expression. Also you should match the beginning and end of the line:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $value);
```

Without `^` and `$`, an input like `somewords!@#` would validate.

Comment: Thanks, figure I can just add the delimiters when using them in php, and leave them out while rendering html.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify delimiters! Try

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have delimiters on that expression in PHP.

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delimiters in php.

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $value);
```